# VB.NET - Unable to retrieve the first ID on a table using SELECT query

Tags: vb.net, select, ms-access-2010

Good day everyone! After 3 years without using VB.NET I decided to use again for my project that not require web development.

this is my code (Reference: [link](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/26801/insert-update-delete-search-values-in-ms-access-20))

```
    cmdOLEDB.CommandText = "SELECT Price FROM tblPrice"

    cmdOLEDB.Connection = cnnOLEDB

    Dim rdrOLEDB As OleDbDataReader = cmdOLEDB.ExecuteReader
    Dim priceList(18) As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    If rdrOLEDB.Read = True Then
        While rdrOLEDB.Read()
            priceList(i) = rdrOLEDB.GetValue(0)
            i += 1
        End While

        txtPrice1.Text = priceList(0).ToString

        cnnOLEDB.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox("Record not found.")
        cnnOLEDB.Close()
    End If
```

when I put this code in a MsgBox

```
MsgBox(rdrOLEDB.GetValue(0))
```

the result is "2" but I have 1 more data before that. It means the query retrieve the ID # 2 not the ID # 1. Here's the screenshot on my Access database

[image]

and when I use this code:

```
txtPrice1.Text = priceList(17).ToString
```

the result is 35.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are skipping the first record because you call two times the Read method.
The first call reads the first record and returns true, then you enter the while loop extracting the info, but at this point you are on the second record.

If you want to check if there are rows then call HasRows

```
If rdrOLEDB.HasRows Then
    While rdrOLEDB.Read()
        priceList(i) = rdrOLEDB.GetValue(0)
        i += 1
    End While

    txtPrice1.Text = priceList(0).ToString

    cnnOLEDB.Close()
Else
    MsgBox("Record not found.")
    cnnOLEDB.Close()
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check with If condition , replace rdrOLEDB.Read with rdrOLEDB.hasrows

```
 If rdrOLEDB.Hasrows= True Then
```

and check it again.

Comment: wow! Thanks a lot! can you explain and when to use the .Read and .Hasrows?

Comment: You can refer to steve's example , because of rdrOLEDB.Read() you are skipping first row :-)